# How one can check his or her access to a particular resource in a restful api?

Tags: rest

Let's say we have the resource: `api/v1/cars/{id}`

How one can actually know whether he or she can have access to this particular resource? `api/v1/auth/cars/{id}`?

Comment: Simply send the request to the endpoint. If you aren't allowed a respective error response will tell you that you aren't allowed to access the resource anyway

Comment: @RomanVottner don't you think it's overkill that if you have access to, you may end up downloading the data for nothing?

Comment: Then send a [HEAD](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.2) request to the same URI ...

Comment: @RomanVottner that was among the solutions I thought about, problem is HEAD just like GET would involve processing based on http error status code... is it better to have another resource to just check and have a body with say a boolean or something?

Comment: HTTP at its core is just a protocol that allows the managment of resources over the internet. Any business rules you infer from the document management are just side effects of the document management itself. REST isn't further about pretty URIs but about decoupling clients and servers by putting the focus on well-defined media types and letting servers provide any information a client will ever need in responses, including links a client can simply invoke by looking up the meaning of the accompanying link-relation name. If pure performance is your issue, then REST isn't your best choice!

Comment: I know what are REST constraints, but hard to tell since there is no official "actual" standard about the "best" solution it seems to be highly subjective... =/
I am not much concerned about performance in this case, I thought it was bad practice to infer that sort of business rule. I thought there was a common sense / best practice.

Comment: @RomanVottner alright let me put it this way: according to you using say api/v1/auth/me/cars/{id} to check the access to api/v1/cars/{id} would be worse than leveraging the potential HEAD error code?

Comment: It is questionable what you gain from such a "resource". What i.e. prevents you from checking first if the user is allowed to perform the generation and returning an error before all of the processing? The client is usually not interested in whether the data is already located in its own file, is a db entry or needs to be calculated by calling plenty other services. It is just interested in the final result. If you need to process some data beforehand is just some internal detail. Probably one of the best advice how to implement it in a RESTful way would be: how would you do it for web-pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First it would have been better to have something else than just leveraging resources just in order to browse in an Angular app (I fully acknowledge that point) like for example using Identity framework with ASP.NET.

Anyway back to the point, I listed a few solutions

- GET `api/v1/cars/{id}` and leverage the error code
- HEAD `api/v1/cars/{id}` and still leverage the error code without transferring a whole body
- OPTIONS `api/v1/cars/{id}` (a bit twisted but does not return an error) to know whether is actually gettable
- Another resource, e.g.

  - GET `api/v1/cars/{id}/authorized`
  - GET `api/v1/auth/me/cars/{entityId}`

I ended up using the first solution and use resolve guard in my Angular app, the most "standard" way of achieving it, even though I found that personally ugly.